# How to make a media library image searchable with few keywords rather just the item name?

Tags: content-search, media-library

Simply wondering how to tag an image with a few different keywords and find it that way later on within the media library. It seems like currently the search function of the media library only picks up on the terms within the file name and nothing else. (using sitecore 8.2)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to explore Sitecore Cognitive Services which is an integration between Sitecore and Microsoft Cognitive Services. The foundation of Sitecore Cognitive Services uses Sitecore's Content Search to analyze text and images with a number of cognitive API's. The analyses is based on computed fields so content is indexed as it's created and will store the analysis in the index.

For your specific requirement about Advanced Image Search, Sitecore Cognitive Services are equipped with:

- Visual Analysis
- Emotional Analysis
- Facial Analysis
- Text Analysis etc.

For more details please checkout the URls below:

**Sitecore Symposium 2017: Sitecore Cognitive Services Presentation:-**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8aRrj_uWMk

**Blog post by Mark Stiles:**
https://markstiles.net/blog/2017/2/22/sitecore-cognitive-services/

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely want a computed field here.  As for what to put in the computed field- it depends.  If you have alternative text, that would be great.  Otherwise, you will need to do some image processing at indexing time to infer what the image may be related to.

As Amitabh pointed out, you can use something like [Azure Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) to do this.

As for setting up the computed field, there are a ton of tutorials out there.  I've [blogged about how to manipulate what goes into the visualization field](https://jockstothecore.com/searching-page-datasources/) before.  It would be a very similar approach in your case.

Hope this helps!